# Current quarter variable issue

Tags: sql

I have the below Query I am trying to genialize the dates to calculate current quarter in Sienese.
[image].Am I doing something wrong and what will be the correct way?

I have tried concat(year(current_date()),'Q',quarter(current_date())).It works in dbvisualizer but not in sisense.

Answer (score 0):

The message is indicating a value you are trying to convert to date is null, it is not a matter of how you convert it, it is that null can never be converted to anything.  You can review the data and change the conditions of what gets returned to avoid that, or use ISNULL() for error control possibly by specifying a date to use by default..

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp